# sessions management in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, session, rest

I am trying to do a simple android application that communicates with a Spring server.

I'd like to use Sessions to store data of each logged in User.
My App exchange Json objects with the server and the Request Mapping is like this:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private IUserDao userDao;

@RequestMapping( value = "/loginJson",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody loginResponse login(@RequestBody loginModel login) {
    loginResponse response=userDao.checkCredentials(login.getUsername(),login.getPassword());
    System.out.println("Result="+response.isSuccess());
    System.out.println("Received:"+login.getUsername()+" "+login.getPassword());

    return response;

}
}
```

The controller is working fine, but I can't figure out how to store a sessione variable. I found many documents explaining Spring Sessions, but each of them different from the other.

Someone can suggest me some simple way to do this or some kind of good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by saying Spring session, but you can declare additional HttpSession parameter in your method, and then do whatever you like inside of the method. Is this what you wanted to find out?

Comment: Yes, I wrote Spring session, but it's actually HttpSession.